# Understanding the Landau–Lifshitz–Gilbert (LLG) equation discrepancy in literature

Tags: magnetic-moment, dipole-moment, ferromagnetism

Background, I am a masters student in microelectronics trying to perform some micromagnetic studies.

In some literature, the $\gamma$ in the LLG equation is said to be just the gyromagnetic ratio of electron, for example any of the IEEE papers about Magnetic Tunnel Junctions. Other examples are

1. http://wpage.unina.it/mdaquino/PhD_thesis/main/node29.html
2. [https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~banas/pubs/llg_lncs.pdf](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Ebanas/pubs/llg_lncs.pdf)
3. https://fse.studenttheses.ub.rug.nl/19849/1/Bachelor_Thesis_Mihai_Andrei_Frantiu_truly_final.pdf
4. [https://www.southampton.ac.uk/~rpb/thesis.pdf](https://www.southampton.ac.uk/%7Erpb/thesis.pdf)

But in certain other sources they take the product of $\gamma$ and the $\mu_0$, for example

1. https://repositorio.ul.pt/bitstream/10451/27945/1/ulfc121672_tm_Pedro_Matos.pdf
2. Spin Waves: Theory and Applications, Daniel D Stancil, Anil Prabhakar

In another paper they are just using the reduced gyromagnetic ratio, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.7188.pdf

Please clarify this discrepancy as this is giving me a hard time trying to understand it.

Comment: It's just a matter of unit conventions, probably SI vs. CGS. It's not an important difference, and you should have no problem as long as you stick to one convention.